# I want to order my matrix in row basis (ascending) in C

Tags: c, matrix

I want re-order my matrix in ascending order but it should be in row basis and I'm a little bit stuck and in trouble with it. Here what it looks like.

ex.

```
3 5 4
9 2 8
6 4 8
```

should be;

```
3 4 5
2 8 9
4 6 8
```

But with my code orders everything in ascending order!

```
2 3 4
4 5 6
8 8 9
```

Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define n 3

int main()
{
    int arr[n][n],min,i,j,tmp,y,k,w,z=0,q=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter number: ");
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            z = i;
            q = j;

            min = arr[i][j];
            w = j;

        for (k = i; k < n; k++)
        {
         for (; w < n; w++)
           if (arr[k][w] < min)
           {
            min = arr[k][w];
            z = k;
            q = w;
           }
         w = 0;
        }
       tmp=arr[i][j];
       arr[i][j]=min;
       arr[z][q]=tmp;
     }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: I already mentioned it, my code works. The only problem is (as I give an example in the beginning) it ascendens each element in whole matrix. I want to let it ascend it in row basis.

Check the example above.

@EmmadKareem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here sorting technique is like :

Assume all the element before `|` is sorted

```
|5 4 1 2

select 1st lowest value and insert it in 1st position

1 |4 5 2

select 2nd lowest value and insert it in 2nd position

1 2| 5 4

select 3rd lowest value and insert it in 3rd position

1 2 4| 5

select 4th lowest value and insert it in 4th position

1 2 4 5| ...no elements left :) Sorted order
```

So the implementation will be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define n 3

int main()
{
    int arr[n][n],min,i,j,tmp,y,k,w,z=0,q=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("Enter number: ");
            scanf("%d",&arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            z = j; // assuming that current value is j'th minimum

            min = arr[i][j];
            // Checking the j'th min value of i'th row
            for (k = j +1 ; k < n; k++)
            {
                if (arr[i][k] < min)
                {
                    min = arr[i][k];
                    z = k; // saving j'th min value
                }
            }
            // swapping current value with the j'th min value
            tmp=arr[i][j];
            arr[i][j]=min;
            arr[i][z]=tmp;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What you did in this code? What and where modification are done?

Comment: You should explain your algorithm to do the task.

Comment: @haccks Is it okay now?

Answer (score 0):

not sure at all if i have understood everything but :

void        sort_int_tab(int *tab, unsigned int size)

{

```
unsigned int        i;
unsigned int        j;
int            tmp;

i = 0;
while (i < size)
{
    j = 0;
    while (j < size - 1)
    {
        if (tab[j] > tab[j + 1])
        {
            tmp = tab[j];
            tab[j] = tab[j + 1];
            tab[j + 1] = tmp;
        }
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

}

int i = 0;

while (i < n)

{

```
sort_int_tab(arr[i], n);
i++;
```

}